# Session Timeout manually

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

I have 2 pages on my dummy site in asp.net, (default.aspx and default2.aspx), On default.aspx,  i created session like below

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MySession"] = "WELCOME";
        Session.Timeout = 1;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default2.aspx");
    }
```

and on default2.aspx

```
 if (Session["MySession"] != null)
            Response.Write(Session["MySession"]);
        else
            Response.Write("Session Timed Out");
```

i was wondering that after 1 min the session will get erase, as i have timeout, but after one minute when i click on the button it redirected me to default2.aspx, and displayed a session value "WELCOME". can anyone tell me how to erase session value after particular duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Default.aspx` you have to check if it is not a post back otherwise the session will be initialized again for each button click

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if(!Page.isPostBack())
        {
          Session["MySession"] = "WELCOME";
          Session.Timeout = 1;
        }
  }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("default2.aspx");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually, what i am doing is, i open the default.aspx page, and kept it open for 1min, and after that i clicked on the button, so that it redirects to default2.aspx, if i use the above technique, my session will never get set, because after postback, default2.aspx will load and not default.aspx

Comment: It should get set only when Default.aspx first Load
I have edited my answer with all the code you need

Comment: hmmm its seems working, can you tell me what was the difference between your code and mine, you set the Not IsPostback condition and i set that it should directly run that code when the page loads, so what made the difference

Comment: The code wrapped in the IsPostBack will be execute only at the first page Load. you could add a couple a break point and debug it to better understand what is going on

Comment: i understood the difference, if i dont place the Not Postback condition, it will again go inside the page_load and execute the code after i clicks the button and again reset the session value and timeout value, anyways, thanks for your help